# Javascript addClass or removeClass not working in subclass after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax script that inserts a value if it is not in the database and removes the value if it is already there, and returns 1 or 0 accordingly, based on the return value it adds or removes a class in the existing button.

I have tried with `find()` to take the subclass value but still it is not working.

```html
<form method="post" class="wish" action="process.php">
  <input type='hidden' id='value' name='value' value='1'>
  <button type="submit" class="card-fox list active" >fan</button>
</form>
```

This line has active I want it to be added if it is not there and remove if it is there.

below is the ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $(".wish").on('submit', (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "process.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          $(".list", this).addClass("active");
        }
        if (data == 2) {
          $(".list", this).removeClass("active");
        }
      },
      error: function (e) {}
    });
  }));
});
```

the problem is that although the ajax script is being executed and everything else is working, the active class is neither adding or removing.

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Have you checked if `$(".list", this)` return any elements at all? I think you might be limiting the context wrong here, `this` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: FYI, if your server-side script can return only 1 or 0, you don’t need any ifs here - you can use _one_ `toggleClass` call instead, and pass your value in as second parameter.

Comment: there will be dynamic forms with same class name, so i need that to be affected only the form which the user has clicked not toggle all the forms that has that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".wish").find('button').addClass("active");
$(".wish").find('button').removeClass("active");
```

Or:

```
//when form is submit, make a copy of this
let self = this;

//send ajax
//in success ajax
$(self).find('button').addClass("active");
```

Greetings!

Comment: "//when form is submit, make a copy of this
let self = this;

//send ajax
//in success ajax
$(self).find('button').addClass("active");" part did the job.

Comment: i still had a question, why do we need to define self when submitting.

Comment: Is a trick to preserve the context of this. Because when you submit the form the context of this is the form, but when you send ajax request to server, the context of this change to response of ajax request. Is the reason to create a self variable, to preserve the context of form.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your ajax success function is not the form.
You can set the context of the ajax call to the for to address this.

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, //<- this this is the form, and tells jQuery to set the this of its callbacks to the form
```

Comment: yes, so the list sub-class in this form should be affected right? but it does not do anything.

Comment: Are you sure `data` returned by the ajax call is exactly 1 or 2?

Comment: yes, I have rechecked it by using alert(data) with data returned.